# Interpolating colors inside a contour in opencv [python]

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am dealing with some images which contain tables and there are 1 or 2 stickers on them. What I am trying to do is getting rid of those stickers. Using color thresholding (in HSV) and contour detection I am able to create a mask for those stickers. Now I want those stickers to "dissolve" out from there (I don't know the correct term for this). While keeping those tables lines intact, so that my line detection works well (which I have to do after this cleaning).
I tried OpenCV's [inpaint](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html). But this doesn't work well here, because the sticker size is big enough.

See this example:

1. Part of the whole image where the sticker is sticking (inside contents are censored by me). It can be over horizontal lines, or vertical lines, or both. Basically, it's sticking somewhere on the table (maybe over some text too, but that can't be recovered anyway). The background won't be necessary whitish, it can be pink/orange/other colors.
   [image]
2. This is the thresholded image, creating a mask of the sticker. We can also get the contour of this if required.
   [image]
3. This is the result of `cv.inpaint()` with radius 3.
   [image]
   What I want is to reconstruct those lines.

### My solution

Now my approach is to interpolate the colors in between the sticker contour, to fill it up. For each pixel inside the contour, I will do a vertical interpolation and a horizontal interpolation (interpolation of the boundary colors) and then fill that pixel with the average of both. I am hoping that this will preserve my vertical and horizontal lines at least. (Might fail if it's on a corner of the table). This will also keep the background smooth, my background can have some different colors.

Now my problem is how I can implement this. What I have are contours that I find using OpenCV's `get_contours()`. I don't know how to get the colors on its boundary and how to interpolate the in-between colors.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Due to confidentiality, I cannot share the whole image.

### EDIT

I tried the seam-carving method ([implementation](https://github.com/andrewdcampbell/seam-carving)). Here are the results:

1. Vertical seaming
   [image]
2. Horizontal seaming
   [image]

It works well once I know which one to use. And I am not sure how well it will do when we have both horizontal and vertical lines.

PS. Don't suggest a solution which needs to find lines and then work. Because there will be many lines in my whole image.

Comment: Please post an input image so we can see what you are doing. Also post your code as text. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @fmw42 Okay sir. I added a few images, hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your problem now, but do not have any readily available solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make synthetic example images. To better explain your issue.
As I got it you can use [Poisson image editing](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Edcor/Graphics/adv-slides/PoissonImageEditing06.pdf). Just take a piece of clear paper image and paste it using poisson blending and the mask you extracted.

Check [this github repo as instance](https://github.com/gray0018/Poisson-image-editing) for examples with code.

Comment: Hi Andrey. I added a few images to make it more clear. Hope this helps.